# Calculate a running count (store population) in SQL using entry and exit timestamps

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 24-hour store and I have a bunch of data points for customer entry and exit timestamps.  I want to know how many customers were in the store at any given time.

My data looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE Events (CustomerID INT, EventDTS DATETIME2, Delta INT);
```

Delta is always either 1 or -1 and represents the change in store population.  For every customer entry event, there is eventually a customer exit event.

I want to know what the occupancy of the store was at any given point in time.  I don't know how to do this efficiently in SQL (MS SQL Server 2012).

This is what I want:

```
select * from EventsWithPopulation;
CustomerID |            EventDTS | Delta | Polulation
         1 | 2014-01-01 00:01:00 |     1 |          0
         2 | 2014-01-01 00:04:00 |     1 |          1
         3 | 2014-01-01 00:05:00 |     1 |          2
         1 | 2014-01-01 00:07:00 |    -1 |          3
         3 | 2014-01-01 00:07:00 |    -1 |          2
         2 | 2014-01-01 00:09:00 |    -1 |          1
```

I've tried creating a cursor to iterate over the data and apply the delta to a running count variable, but this is very slow.  It's on the order of 3 million rows and it takes 5 minutes to compute the running count the events - I'm looking for a way to do it in a few seconds.

Comment: It is not clear for me why do you have to iterate and apply the delta. If you need the population in a given time, don't you have it directly in your table?

Comment: Why is the `Population` 0 at the first time... shouldn't it be 1, since there's a single "Enter" delta?

Comment: @chezy525 - I want to know how many people were in the store immediately before the event happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using SQL Server 2012, so you can use cumulative sum.  That makes this easy:

```
select ewp.*,
       sum(Delta) over (order by EventDTS) as Population
from EventsWithPopulation ewp;
```

This will give you the population at the instant after any event occurred.

EDIT:

The above looks a bit strange when there are multiple time stamps that are exactly the same.  You can fix this by putting something in to make them distinct, presumably the customer di:

```
select ewp.*,
       sum(Delta) over (order by EventDTS, CustomerId) as Population
from EventsWithPopulation ewp;
```

Comment: I thought this looked correct, but I couldn't get it to work in the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df41c/2

Comment: @sgeddes . . . It is correct.  It just looks strange when two time stamps are exactly the same.  Add `CustomerId` to the `order by` and you'll get more intuitive results.

Comment: That makes more sense.  You could subtract 1 to account for the first row offset to 0, but that doesn't feel right to me to get a true running total.  Nonetheless, at least this is closer without the overhead of a correlated subquery.

Comment: This is basically what I was looking for and I can make it work for my purposes, I think.  I was vaguely aware of the `sum over` operation, but I thought it required a `partition by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's answer will list the population for each event.  If you want to give it a time and get the population, just sum the delta between midnight and now.

```
declare @mydate DateTime
set @mydate = GetDate()

Select 
  sum(delta) + 1
from
 EventsWithPopulation
where
  EventDTS between DateAdd(Day, Datediff(Day,0,@mydate), 0) and @mydate
```

EDIT: As the enter event doesnt reflect immediately in the row, but rather on the next event.  Delta is always behind by one.  I've added one from the delta sum to adjust for this.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df41c/12)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the window function will return your desired results.  I think you'll need to use a correlated subquery along with `row_number`:

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over (order by eventdts) rn
  from Events
  )
select *, 
  coalesce((select sum(delta)
   from cte e2
   where e2.rn < e.rn
   ),0) population
from cte e
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df41c/6)

Comment: This is a neat solution, and it is along the lines of what I expected I would need, but it does not perform well.  For my data set it takes longer to do it this way than to use a cursor and iterate over the rows keeping tally of the store population manually.